# Django: Non-primary Foreign Key object can't access related model instance

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I'm new in Django. I have 2 class **tech_system** adn **equiptment** in models.py

```
class tech_system(models.Model):
    id_tech_system = models.BigAutoField(db_column='ID_tech_system', primary_key=True)
    system_descript_short = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    #More field here
    tech_system_code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=40)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tech_system'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.system_descript_short

        
class equiptment(models.Model):
    id_thietbi = models.BigAutoField(db_column='ID_thietbi', primary_key=True)
    tech_system_code = models.ForeignKey('tech_system', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column="tech_system_code", blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'equiptment'
```

I use python shell, equiptment model object can't access to related tech_system model instance. I got the error matching query does not exist.
I want to get the value **obj1.equiptment.tech_system_code.system_descript_short**. How can I do?

Thank you.

```
>>> obj1 = equiptment.objects.first()
>>> obj1.tech_system_code_id
'530'
>>> obj1.tech_system_code
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dev1\env1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 173, in __get__
    rel_obj = self.field.get_cached_value(instance)
  File "D:\Dev1\env1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\mixins.py", line 15, in get_cached_value
    return instance._state.fields_cache[cache_name]
KeyError: 'tech_system_code'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Dev1\env1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 187, in __get__
    rel_obj = self.get_object(instance)
  File "D:\Dev1\env1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 154, in get_object
    return qs.get(self.field.get_reverse_related_filter(instance))
  File "D:\Dev1\env1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 437, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
app.models.tech_system.DoesNotExist: tech_system matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: BTW, `equiptment` has a typo

Comment: One question, does the referenced row in fact exist in the target table?

Comment: Hi Jiri Baum,

The ref row exist.
`>>> tech_system.objects.filter(tech_system_code='530').values()
<QuerySet [{'id_tech_system': 32, 'system_descript_short': 'PT-VPC', 'system_year': 0, 'system_drawing': None,
'system_doc_btbd': None, 'system_doc_vh': None, 'system_type_id': 'TTB-MD', 'dept_code_id': 'VPC', 'tech_system_code': '530'}]>`

Comment: default foreign key refer to primary key and your primary key is id_tech_system and value is 32 not 530

Comment: Hi pouria farhadi,
Yup, I know, but the database schema cant change. As you can see, the foreign key refer to non-primary key field with "db_column" field as I declare here `tech_system_code = models.ForeignKey('tech_system', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column="tech_system_code", blank=True, null=True)`.  In Python shell, the value **obj1.tech_system_code_id**  return '530' not "32".

Comment: what happens when you change:
'tech_system'
to tech_system in the line:
tech_system_code = models.ForeignKey('tech_system', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column="tech_system_code", blank=True, null=True)

Answer (score 0):

I found that tech_system_code record is assigned as str type, not an object in equiptment model. Record values imported to the database is not correct.
Thanks for your help.